# How do i access my selected item ? ListBox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox

i have ListBox on my xaml page called MainListBox. i can get index that get selected, but how can i get the data from selected item ?

My MainListBox_SelectionChanged :

```
private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int noteID1 = MainListBox.SelectedIndex+1;

        if (MainListBox.SelectedIndex != null)
        {


            //I can get the index that get selected, 
            Debug.WriteLine(MainListBox.SelectedIndex);



        }

         MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }
```

my XAML :

```
<ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="6,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged" Height="578" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Text="{Binding noteName}" Margin="-2,-13,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="DetailsText" Text="{Binding noteText}" Margin="10,-6,0,3" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="noteIdText" Text="{Binding noteID}" Margin="10,-6,0,3" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Please someone guide me, thanks. :)

Comment: Checking whether `MainListBox.SelectedIndex` is null after computing note ID from that value is pointless. A `NullReferenceException` will be thrown before your check ever executes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried MainListBox.SelectedItem ?

var data = MainListBox.Selecteditem as [type of class bounded to listbox] ;

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'Selecteditem', :(, seems not working mate. any idea ? btw, thanks.

Comment: Ah, Thank You man. i need to just uppercase the i in SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the `Items` object that you're binding the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` property to is a collection of objects of the class `MyDataObject`. Then, within the selection changed callback use the following:

```
MyDataObject obj = ( (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext ) as MyDataObject;
int noteID = obj.noteID;
```

Comment: what is MyDataObject Actually ?, if i didn't use my data object, use var. use this method var data = ((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext); Debug.WriteLine(data); , the output is wp7_App.MainNotes, looks like it's in right direction. any idea to get the noteID ?, thanks

Comment: MyDataObject is the class that contains the fields noteName, noteText and noteID. In your case it looks like the class name is MainNotes. And you can use the var keyword instead of the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for fast reply.

finally i figure it out.

```
 if (MainListBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {


            var data = MainListBox.SelectedItem as Notes;

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?noteID=" + data.noteID, UriKind.Relative));


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectedItem is the entity in the Items. You can directly convert to the entity type.

Also SelectedItem must be in System.Windows.Control.ListBox in WP7. Here is the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: Also, I don't think your MainListBox.SelectedIndex != null is right. SelectedIndex is integer which is always not be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MyList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataModel data = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as DataModel;
    // data.MyPropertyHere;
}
```